# Test custom implementation of Spring JpaRepository

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, entitymanager

I have a custom implementation of a Spring JpaRepository that uses the EntityManager as injected with `@PersistenceContext` to call the `createNativeQuery()` method. The reason I can't go with the standard `@Query` on the repository interface is that I need to build the query dynamically.

I cannot find any standard solution on how to test this kind of DAO. If I simply go with a `@DataJpaTest`, H2 complains that it cannot find my database. I have several other standard JpaRepositories in the codebase that are tested exactly like that.

One possible solution could be to `@Autowire` the entityManager in the test class and then inject it via a setter to the repository implementation instantiated with a normal Java `new`, but it still complains that H2 cannot find my database.

My configuration:

```
public interface FooDao extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long>, CustomFooDao {}
public interface CustomFooDao {
    List<Foo> query();
}
public class CustomFooDaoImpl implements CustomFooDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public void query() {
        return entityManager.createNativeQuery(someFancyQueryLiteral).getResultList();
    }
}
```

My test:

```
@DataJpaTest
class CustomFooImplTest {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private CustomFooDaoImpl customFooDaoImpl;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        customFooDaoImpl = new CustomFooDaoImpl();
        customFooDaoImpl.setEntityManager(entityManager);
    }
```

The exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "my_database" not found; 
...
```

Comment: Do you have `test/resource/application-test.properties` with some information about db, something like this:

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:my_database
spring.datasource.username=sa

Comment: Yep, I have on my test ```@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test"} @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE) @DataJpaTest```